# Why do relative paths not work in CMS?

Tags: path, content-management-system, relative-path

Why do relative paths not work in popular basic Content Management Systems which use "editable" class tagging? It's weird that every time I edit a page in the CMS all my styles and jS are killed because of my relative paths. What's going on behind the scenes? Are they making a duplicate copy of my page? Although that still doesn't seem to quite explain it, because forward relative paths such as

`/css/style.css` will still work,

but relative paths going backward such as

```
../css/style.css
```

will no longer work.

Even if they make a duplicate copy, they have FTP access and it seems like they should be able to trace relative paths... Instead they need an absolute or root-relative path.

Comment: Which CMS? There are literally hundreds of them...

Comment: For example pagelime, surrealcms and I think cushycms

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths work fine in Surreal, but if your page has include files then the paths may "break" depending on where the page that's including it is located.

Regardless, you can adjust URL formatting pretty easily in Surreal:

```
<div class="editable" data-urls="absolute">
    ...
</div>
```

More details are in the docs: http://www.surrealcms.dev/docs/url-formatting